# Java - playing some of *.wav files outside of IDE fails

Tags: java, audio, wav, playback

I have 3 wav files from 3 different sources, and only one file is working. Everything runs fine in Eclipse, but whenever I compile it, it doesn't. That are short clips < 1 second. One of them should be played, when I hover over the Buttons.  Here is the code I use for playblack:

```
static EventHandler<MouseEvent> menuHover =new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

try{        
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
File menuHover = new File("menuhover.wav");
AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(menuHover.getAbsoluteFile());

clip.open(inputStream);
clip.start(); 
clip.setFramePosition(0);
} catch (Exception g) {
g.printStackTrace();
}

}
};
```

The one that is working has a format of (PCM_UNSIGNED 22050.0 Hz, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame)

And the one that isn't (PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian)

I converted the not working files, to the same format as the working one, but it still doesn't work. I checked, if the file output has the correct path, it has. I don't get any errors.

Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: In what way isn't it working? Are you getting and exception? If so, include the stack trace.

Comment: Nope, I don't get any exception, I just can't hear the sound.

Comment: My best luck has been with 44100 FPS, 16 bit, stereo. I didn't know Java supported 48000 fps, am not sure that it does. If there was an objection to the format you should have gotten an unrecognized format error. Once jarred, run from console and show us an error message. Last minor point: it is better to use SourceDataLine than Clip, if above is your standard usage. SDL goes directly from file to output, via buffer units. Clip (if loaded and played at same time, as you do) goes entirely to RAM then (only after entirely loaded) from RAM to output via buffer units.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for your response. My problem is, I don't get any error messages when I run it from the console, but I don't hear the sound either. I will try to use SourceDataLine as you recommended, maybe that will help. This isn't my standard usage, since I'm pretty new to it. I have noticed, that sometimes it will play this file once, when I hover over the menu, and then never again, even if I relaunch it, which I find very strange.